# eas build production crash but npx expo start work perfectly

Tags: react-native, build, expo, eas

I upgraded my expo app from sdk45 to 49 and had to change some codes in accordance with the change.

Testing the app with 'npx expo start' works perfectly but ,when building the apk with both local and on eas cloud (eas build --platform android --local), the app crash immediately that the splash screen has not yet shown up and the app keeps stopping dialog occurred. The adb logcat gave me this :

```
--------- beginning of crash
01-18 18:29:28.019  5609  5609 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8 in tid 5609 (c.eACDS.hybrid2), pid 5609 (c.eACDS.hybrid2)
01-18 18:29:28.051  5678  5678 I crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstoneProto
01-18 18:29:28.051   213   213 I tombstoned: received crash request for pid 5609
01-18 18:29:28.052  5678  5678 I crash_dump64: performing dump of process 5609 (target tid = 5609)
01-18 18:29:28.191  5609  5661 I ReactNativeJS: Running "main
01-18 18:29:28.209  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreensShadowNode
01-18 18:29:28.213  5609  5662 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 289878283; UID 10193; state: DISABLED
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_x86_64/emu64xa:14/UE1A.230829.036.A1/11228894:user/release-keys'
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86_64'
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2024-01-18 18:29:28.063270894+0700
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : Process uptime: 2s
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : Cmdline: com.seafdec.eACDS.hybrid2
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : pid: 5609, tid: 5609, name: c.eACDS.hybrid2  >>> com.seafdec.eACDS.hybrid2 <<<
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : uid: 10193
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0000000000000008
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :     rax 0000000000000000  rbx 00007362c4411000  rcx 0000000000000001  rdx 0000000000000002
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :     r8  000073643826f000  r9  0000000000000000  r10 000000005b1c4f38  r11 000073610676a8d0
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :     r12 0000000000000001  r13 00007ffc9ac4a080  r14 00007362e437a150  r15 00007362e437a178
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :     rdi 00007ffc9ac4a080  rsi 0000736294345d50
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :     rbp 00007ffc9ac4a050  rsp 00007ffc9ac4a020  rip 0000736106750213
01-18 18:29:28.255  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : 31 total frames
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0000000000081213  /data/app/~~-o1I18AvGwKxQrTzPhWFRQ==/com.seafdec.eACDS.hybrid2-JLVeJHpsRd1A4rYK_-nCaQ==/lib/x86_64/libreanimated.so (BuildId: d0be42da2b9965efa4d1960bf04a785be40c510a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 0000000000098c04  /data/app/~~-o1I18AvGwKxQrTzPhWFRQ==/com.seafdec.eACDS.hybrid2-JLVeJHpsRd1A4rYK_-nCaQ==/lib/x86_64/libreanimated.so (reanimated::Scheduler::triggerUI()+228) (BuildId: d0be42da2b9965efa4d1960bf04a785be40c510a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 000000000009c911  /data/app/~~-o1I18AvGwKxQrTzPhWFRQ==/com.seafdec.eACDS.hybrid2-JLVeJHpsRd1A4rYK_-nCaQ==/lib/x86_64/libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (reanimated::AndroidScheduler::*)(), &(reanimated::AndroidScheduler::triggerUI()), reanimated::AndroidScheduler, void>::dispatch(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*>)+33) (BuildId: d0be42da2b9965efa4d1960bf04a785be40c510a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 000000000009c884  /data/app/~~-o1I18AvGwKxQrTzPhWFRQ==/com.seafdec.eACDS.hybrid2-JLVeJHpsRd1A4rYK_-nCaQ==/lib/x86_64/libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::detail::FunctionWrapper<void (*)(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*>), facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*, void>::call(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, void (*)(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*>))+52) (BuildId: d0be42da2b9965efa4d1960bf04a785be40c510a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 000000000009b8f0  /data/app/~~-o1I18AvGwKxQrTzPhWFRQ==/com.seafdec.eACDS.hybrid2-JLVeJHpsRd1A4rYK_-nCaQ==/lib/x86_64/libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (reanimated::AndroidScheduler::*)(), &(reanimated::AndroidScheduler::triggerUI()), reanimated::AndroidScheduler, void>::call(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+32) (BuildId: d0be42da2b9965efa4d1960bf04a785be40c510a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 0000000000391a4b  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+219) (BuildId: b6dc79e02101ea00827a35a55ab6597a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 000000000036faed  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3837) (BuildId: b6dc79e02101ea00827a35a55ab6597a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 0000000000a2bf3c  /data/app/~~-o1I18AvGwKxQrTzPhWFRQ==/com.seafdec.eACDS.hybrid2-JLVeJHpsRd1A4rYK_-nCaQ==/oat/x86_64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.reanimated.Scheduler$1.run+28)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00000000003707e5  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7157) (BuildId: b6dc79e02101ea00827a35a55ab6597a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 0000000000a2bf7c  /data/app/~~-o1I18AvGwKxQrTzPhWFRQ==/com.seafdec.eACDS.hybrid2-JLVeJHpsRd1A4rYK_-nCaQ==/oat/x86_64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.reanimated.Scheduler$2.runGuarded+12)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 000000000036fa88  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3736) (BuildId: b6dc79e02101ea00827a35a55ab6597a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 00000000003a3970  /data/app/~~-o1I18AvGwKxQrTzPhWFRQ==/com.seafdec.eACDS.hybrid2-JLVeJHpsRd1A4rYK_-nCaQ==/oat/x86_64/base.vdex (com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable.run+0)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 00000000005c4d09  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+89) (BuildId: e4c2202f7e80276bcdbfa046249d896342205aa9)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 00000000005c83ce  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loopOnce+1022) (BuildId: e4c2202f7e80276bcdbfa046249d896342205aa9)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 00000000005c7f01  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+481) (BuildId: e4c2202f7e80276bcdbfa046249d896342205aa9)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 000000000033b44c  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+1628) (BuildId: e4c2202f7e80276bcdbfa046249d896342205aa9)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 0000000000378826  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+806) (BuildId: b6dc79e02101ea00827a35a55ab6597a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 00000000003c538f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+255) (BuildId: b6dc79e02101ea00827a35a55ab6597a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 00000000007f07f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (_jobject* art::InvokeMethod<(art::PointerSize)8>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1476) (BuildId: b6dc79e02101ea00827a35a55ab6597a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 000000000075a387  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*) (.__uniq.165753521025965369065708152063621506277)+39) (BuildId: b6dc79e02101ea00827a35a55ab6597a)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 00000000000a3ac0  /system/framework/x86_64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+128) (BuildId: c78b6b6270062f2e659e76e5f8dac6d757f47ca6)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 00000000007e66a9  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+137) (BuildId: e4c2202f7e80276bcdbfa046249d896342205aa9)
01-18 18:29:28.256  5678  5678 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 00000000007f0848  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2872)  fault)
```

The problem is that i can't find any fatal errors from the log,
May be 'unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreensShadowNode'

I have googled it for a day and no clue about how to do with 'unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class'. The full log have many unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater

```
type h01-18 18:29:27.926  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
01-18 18:29:27.927  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
01-18 18:29:27.928  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
01-18 18:29:27.928  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollContainerViewManager
01-18 18:29:27.928  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
01-18 18:29:27.929  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
01-18 18:29:27.929  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
01-18 18:29:27.930  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
01-18 18:29:27.930  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
01-18 18:29:27.930  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager
01-18 18:29:27.931  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
01-18 18:29:27.931  5609  5662 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
```

My project name is eacds and this is its package.json. I try delete node_modules many times but not work. Please help me find the cause of the crash.

```
type her{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "postinstall": "jetify"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "5.0.11",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
    "expo-asset": "~8.10.1",
    "expo-background-fetch": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.5.3",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.18",
    "expokit": "^34.0.2",
    "lz-string": "^1.4.4",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-expo-viewport-units": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-html-parser": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-loading-gif": "github:Manit-Chan/lspg",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-viewport-units": "0.0.5",
    "react-navigation": "^3.13.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
    "save": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.5.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true,
  "overrides": {
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Removing react-native-reanimated solves this problem that app crash on startup and no error in adb logcat.

I can't remember the link that provided this solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).